# Does Bloodborne: The old hunters edition include the standard edition?

Tags: bloodborne

I check the time to beat and notice that **Bloodborne: The old hunters** edition only takes less than 10h to beat while the standard takes more than 30h to beat. So does **Bloodborne: The old hunters** edition include the standard edition? I heard that this game is good so I want to try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, 'The Old Hunters' is DLC and requires already owning the base game to be able to play.

The 10 hours referenced in the time to beat is for the 'The Old Hunters' DLC only.

If you want to buy both the main game and the DLC in one package you need to get the 'Game of the Year' Edition.

Edit: 
Further to Kodama's comment, it seems that 'The Old Hunters ***Edition***' is an Asian region special edition that includes the base game, DLC, soundtrack and strategy guide. This is a physical version of the game, not to be confused with 'The Old Hunters' which is a digital only DLC referenced above.

Comment: I see. I also saw Game of the Year edition but I thought that's The Old Hunters edition with different title for European market. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc I don't think this answer is right for you. "The Old Hunters Edition" is the Asian name for the "Game of the Year Edition". I take it from your name that you are from Vietnam? If so, the "Old Hunters Edition" (note it has to have the word "Edition" in it) should include both the main game and the DLC. Where did you see the "10h to beat" you mentioned in your question and where did you try to buy the game?

Comment: @Colin I'm sorry to correct you again, but the "Old Hunters Edition" really is just the GotY name in Asia. It's not just the physical edition. In Japan the GotY edition got a physical collector's release including the things you mentioned, but there is also a regular one and the digital GotY is called "Old Hunters Edition" as well, being the game and DLC like the Western version. Here is an example from the Thailand store (must be logged out to see it): https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-th/games/bloodborne-the-old-hunters-edition/cid=HP9000-CUSA03023_00-BLOODBORNE0000AS

Comment: @Kodama: I checked the 10h to beat on howlongtobeat site, it's precisely 9h to beat the game. Yes, I'm Vietnamese. I'm planning to buy the ps4 disc in Vietnam. So I guess there is 2 version TOHs, one is digital version buying online which offer DLC only and another version is in ps4 disc which offer the base game as well as DLC. Am I right? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc It's like this: The DLC add-on for Bloodborne is called "The Old Hunters". You need to have the base Bloodborne game to play it. So if you own the base game you can buy the DLC digitally alone without paying for Bloodborne twice. There is also a version that includes both base game and DLC for players like you, who don't have either.  Outside of Asia, this version is called "Game of the Year Edition" and in Asia it's called "The Old Hunters Edition". It's the same thing with a different name.

Comment: Since you're buying it in Asia, if you buy "The Old Hunters Edition" it includes both Bloodborne and DLC. If you buy "The Old Hunters" online as DLC (without the word "Edition") it's only the DLC and requires the base game to play. The DLC alone is only available online, not on disc.  If you buy "The Old Hunters Edition" in retail or digitally, it should include both Bloodborne and DLC. If it has "Edition" in the name it includes both. If you see a "Game of the Year Edition" somewhere, it includes both as well, but it will probably a Western import, unless Vietnam is an exception in Asia.

Comment: @KodamaL Got it. By the way, does this also mean that if a game is sold in ps4 disc(physical as you said), the content cannot include DLC only but also include the base game right? I'm also planning buying ps4 disc Guilty Gear Xrd -REVELATOR- and I have the same concern.

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc Yes, that's usually the way it is here in Europe. I don't know Guilty Gear and maybe it's different in Vietnam, but games in boxes are normally on disc and may include codes for additional DLC to download, but the base game is on disc. There are a few exceptions, but if the game is not on disc and there is only a download code inside, it will say so on the box. There is never a disc that only has DLC on it for which you would need a game that is not also on the disc.

Comment: @Kodama One last question. Does the disc include the DLC installation or there is a code somewhere in the box and I have to use the code to download the DLC?

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc In the European version of Bloodborne, the DLC is on the disc and gets installed with the game, so it will probably be the same in the Asian one. For other games to get additional content there are often download codes in the box that you need to redeem on your PSN account.